# Comparing JPG files with Photoshop Layers

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is it possible to compare filenames for a set of files that are imported as Photoshop layers ?
I have a folder of 50 jpg images which I have used in a PSD file.
Now I want to check whether all the JPG files are used or not ?
Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: You can use ```Folder(path).getFiles('*.jpg')``` to get all jpg files than you can create an array with all files name without extension by pushing. Then  you can use if condition to validate if layer with certain name exists or not like ```app.activeDocument.layers.getByName(i)```. This is how it might be done via Photoshop scripting

Comment: I am a noob in scripting or coding. Can you please help me make one ?

Comment: I can help but I need to know exactly what you're trying to do. I mean what type of layer structure are there in psd. better share an image of containing your layers and your issue so that I can create working script.

Comment: Thx Mr. Online 
OK. This is the scenario :
I have a folder having 100 images. I have made a design in which I have used all the 100 images.
But I am not sure whether I have used all the 100 images or not (in the design image).
So I want a script that would compare the 100 images in the folder with the 100 layers in the PSB file I created.
If any image is missing from the PSB image, it should notify of that image. 
The rule is that all 100 images should be used in the design.
PS : The images will not be duplicated in the PSB image, they will be used once.
Can this be done ?

Comment: Also the layer structure can be random. The only thing concerns is whether those 100 images are used in the file or not.

Comment: Yes this can be achieved completely from photoshop scripting. I'll try it.

Comment: Is layer name is same as PNG file? also the images are embedded or linked? tell me full details of it

Comment: Yes the filenames are same as layer names. Only the extension wont be there in layers.
The images are placed in the files as layers, so yes they are embedded and NOT linked. No linking is there.
All individual images on separate layers.

Comment: @Mr.Online please reply.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I'll fill your request tonight :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said, Photoshop scripting can help you achieve this by using File Objects and basic javascript knowledge. I've modified my old script as you've desired and now it should work well with any nested groups and images.

I highly encourage you to learn scripting and ask questions here wherever you feels confused.

Save below code as 'Script.jsx' and run it from 'File > Scripts > Browse'

Update 2 : Now it saves log.txt file too as per you requested. P.S. Learn from this script and tweak it to your desired result.

```
// Managing Document
var docs = app.documents;

// Progress Bar
var win = new Window("window{text:'Progress',bounds:[100,100,400,150],bar:Progressbar{bounds:[20,20,280,31] , value:0,maxvalue:100}};");

// assigning activeDocument
if (docs.length != 0) {
    var docRef = app.activeDocument;

    // Defining the folder
    alert("You will be prompted for the folder containing your images.\n" +
        "Files will be selected with a '.png'/'.jpg/.jpeg' on the end in the same folder.");
    var folder = Folder.selectDialog();
    if (!folder) {
        exit;
    }

    var photoFiles = folder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i);
    var matchFiles = [];
    var photoFilesName = [];
    //Searching for used images
    var increment = parseFloat(0);
    var divider = parseFloat(100/photoFiles.length);
    win.show();
    for (var i = 0; i < photoFiles.length; i++) {
        increment = increment + divider;
        var indexPhotoName = removeExtension(photoFiles[i].displayName);
        photoFilesName.push(indexPhotoName);
        var doc = activeDocument;
        var curLayer;
        goThroughLayers(doc, indexPhotoName);
    }

    function goThroughLayers(parentLayer, targetName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < parentLayer.layers.length; i++) {
            curLayer = parentLayer.layers[i];
            doc.activeLayer = curLayer;
            if (curLayer.typename == 'LayerSet') {
                goThroughLayers(curLayer, targetName)
            } else {
                if (curLayer.name == targetName) {
                    // if (curLayer.name.match(/[e]/ig)) {
                        matchFiles.push(targetName);
                    // }
                } //end if
            } //end else
        } //end loop
    } //end function


    function arr_diff(a1, a2) {
        var a = [],
            diff = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            a[a1[i]] = true;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            if (a[a2[i]]) {
                delete a[a2[i]];
            } else {
                a[a2[i]] = true;
            }
        }
        for (var k in a) {
            diff.push(k);
        }
        return diff;
    }

    function removeExtension(str) {
        return str.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
    }

    var missItems = arr_diff(matchFiles, photoFilesName);
    if (missItems.length > 0) {
        var missFolder = new Folder(photoFiles[0].path + '/Missed%20Files');
        if(!missFolder.exists){
            missFolder.create();
        }
        for (var y = 0; y < photoFiles.length; y++) {
            var photoTrimName = removeExtension(photoFiles[y].displayName);
            for( var x = 0; x < missItems.length ; x++){
                if(photoTrimName == missItems[x]){
                    photoFiles[y].copy(new File(missFolder+'/'+photoFiles[y].displayName));
                }
            }
        };
        win.close();
        alert("You've missed total " + missItems.length + " files. Press OK to open folder containing missing files. Log report is generated wherever PSD is saved.");
        var FileStr = "";
        for(var m=0; m<missItems.length; m++){
            FileStr = FileStr + '\n' + (m+1) + '. ' + missItems[m];
        }
        var str = "Your missed files are : " + FileStr;
        saveTxt(str);
        missFolder.execute();
    } else {
        win.close();
        saveTxt('All Photos are used');
        alert('All Photos are used');
    }
} else {
    alert('Open atleast one document');
}

function saveTxt(txt)
{
    var Name = "LogReport_" + app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
    var Ext = decodeURI(app.activeDocument.name).replace(/^.*\./,'');
    if (Ext.toLowerCase() != 'psd')
        return;

    var Path = app.activeDocument.path;
    var saveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name +".txt");

    if(saveFile.exists)
        saveFile.remove();

    saveFile.encoding = "UTF8";
    saveFile.open("e", "TEXT", "????");
    saveFile.writeln(txt);
    saveFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I didn't had much time so script is much rough. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for this Mr. Online. I checked it but it is showing error although all the PNG files were used. How can I send you the screenshot of the error ?

Comment: You can upload it to tempory image storing site and then post link in comment. As I've said this is very basic and might occur bug. I can customise it as error free but I got much busy schedule for 2 days

Comment: You can also reach me out via email, you can see it in my profile but I don't think I'll be able to fix it in 2 days

Comment: Wait. I just found that you wanted jpg instead of png. I'm updating my answer. Please resave code and try to run

Comment: Hi Mr. Online. Its the same issue.

Comment: its ok id you can give it after 2 days

Comment: Share error image please. I'll fix after 2 days 

Comment: pls share ur mail address. i dont seem to find it

Comment: I have sent you the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, it is possible to get some information related to PSD file layers using [PSD.js](https://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/) library